# FSOpenFork does not work in 64 bit Lion OSx

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, osx-lion, file-forks

```
FSOpenFork(&fileRef, forkName.length, forkName.unicode, permissions, (FSIORefNum *)forkReference);
```

Is not working properly in 64 bit lion OSX, We can run same project in 32 bit and 64 bit. When we run in 32 bit FSOpenFork returns the data fork reference number, but when we run in 64 bit it does not returns, Anyone has any idea?

Comment: What does it return? And how is `forkReference` defined?

Comment: typedef NSFileHandle* FileReference; It suppose to return fork reference, Later i want pass this reference number, But that method returns as -38 error, File Not opened

Comment: That's still not the definition of `forkReference`. I'm trying to figure out why you're using a cast there, because `FSIORefNum` is a different size on 64-bit and that might be causing your problem.